# laravel passport always returns unauthorised

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-passport, nuxt.js

In my project i am using laravel and nuxt with laravel passport.

For some reason laravel passport always returns the message 'unauthorized' when i try to register a user.

In api.php I created a route that references to the create function in my authcontroller:

`Route::post('create', 'AuthController@create');`

This is my Authcontroller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function local()
    {
        return response()->json(['user' => auth()->user()]);
    }

    public function oauth()
    {
        return response()->json(auth()->user());
    }

    public function create(request $request){

        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:12',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed'
        ]);        

        $user = User::create($validatedData);

        $accesToken = $user->createToken('authToken')->accessToken;     

        return response()->json([
            'user' => $user,
            'access_token' => $accessToken
        ]);
    }
}
```

In postman i try to register a user with some data,

I am making a post **request to 127.0.0.1:8000/api/create**

In the Headers tab i have a key, **accept** with the value **application/json**
In the body of my request i send the following data as form-data:

- name = testuser
- email = test@admin.com
- password = secret
- password_confirmation = secret

But somehow i always get the message unauthorized... I am sure this is the right URI. I think this problem has something to do with laravel passport but cant seem to figure out why i am being redirected. When i remove the accept key from my header in postman i am simply being redirected to the login page of laravel. I think that somehow somewhere in passport all routes require authorization...

If someone has a solution or usefull information that would be great! :)

Comment: https://medium.com/techcompose/create-rest-api-in-laravel-with-authentication-using-passport-133a1678a876

follow this doc

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to get token from URL `/oauth/token` and use it as bearer token on your `create` request. I think that the Api middleware expects to receive a token.

Header example:

```
'headers' => [
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$accessToken, //From route /oauth/token
],
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the anwser! But  i am not using the api middleware. What i want to do is take this route without using laravel passport. Do you have any idea on how to achieve this? thanks